# Plane and line segment intersection

Tags: geometry

I have a plane represented by the equation **ax + by + cz + d = 0**, and I know its 4 vertices
and have a line segment represented by its two endpoints

How to check if the line cross the plane by the given information ?

I found some solution but all with parametric vector and vectors generally, I don't want solutions with vectors, I want a geometric one

Comment: By $4$ vertices do you know $a, b, c, d$?

Comment: I mean by "By 4 vertices" that I know its left-top vertex and right-top etc..
And yes I know a, b, c, d of the equation

Comment: Do you mean the infinite plane or the plane confined by your four vertices?

Comment: The plane confined by my vertices

Comment: When you calculate the value of the equation by inserting the end "points", you should get a result with same sign if there is no intersection and different signs if there is intersection. To check if it is in the rectangle created by the 4 vertices you use the lines equations. I am sure somewhere on th enet you can find a detailed solution.